# How to add second breadcrumb

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I have a node type with a multivalue taxonomy term reference field. In a custom module I altered the breadcrumb to show the hierarchical terms too.
But this works only for the first term.

My question is: How can I generate more than one breadcrumb, if there are multiple terms associated to that node.

This is what I have:

```
Home > ParentTerm1 > Term1 > NodeTitle
```

I need this:

```
Home > ParentTerm1 > Term1 > NodeTitle
Home > ParentTerm2 > Term2 > NodeTitle
```

But the breadcrumb build doesn't work with that format.

I'm new to drupal 8 and new to the OOP way of programming, so any help is appreciated!

This is my custom BreadcrumbBuilder:

```
namespace Drupal\clio_breadcrumbs\Breadcrumb;

use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb;
use Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;

class ClioBreadcrumbBuilder implements BreadcrumbBuilderInterface {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $attributes) {
      $parameters = $attributes->getParameters()->all();
      // need Clio-Breadcrumbs only for full view node type 'werk'
      // so it should be applied on node page ONLY.
      if (isset($parameters['node']) && !empty($parameters['node'])) {
        return TRUE;
      }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
      $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
      $node_type = $node->bundle();

      if ($node_type == 'werk') {

        // $cat_id_array = $node->field_kategorie->referencedEntities();
        // $count_cat = count($cat_id_array);
        // dump($count_cat);

        $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
        $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute('Home', '<front>'));

        if (!empty($node->field_kategorie->entity)) {
          $term = $node->field_kategorie->entity;
          $storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('taxonomy_term');
          $parents = $storage->loadParents($term->id());
          // output parent terms
          if (!empty($parents)) {
            foreach ($parents as $parent) {
              $pps = $storage->loadParents($parent->id());
              if (!empty($pps)) {
                foreach ($pps as $pp) {
                  $ppps = $storage->loadParents($pp->id());
                  if (!empty($ppps)) {
                    foreach ($ppps as $ppp) {
                      $breadcrumb->addLink($ppp->toLink());
                    }
                  }
                  $breadcrumb->addLink($pp->toLink());
                }
              }
              $breadcrumb->addLink($parent->toLink());
            }
          }
          $breadcrumb->addLink($term->toLink());
        }
      } else { // Not Node-Type werk
        $breadcrumb = new Breadcrumb();
        $breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute('Home', '<front>'));
      }

      $breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(['route']);

      return $breadcrumb;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how you want to have that displayed, but the breadcrumb system can't handle multiple breadcrumbs in any way. You can either create your own block and display there whatever you want (and then hide the default breadcrumb block on node/* for example) or make it part of the node template itself.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question to show, what I need.
I think, building a custom block is the way to go. Or - just got the idea - it should be possible to use views module for that...